# Jmodel get articles of an attribute

Tags: joomla-3.x, com-content, jmodel

I'd like to get articles of a certain attribute, how do I achieve it.
Below is a code I get to get an article of an id:

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.model');
JModel::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/models');
$Model = JModel::getInstance('Article', 'ContentModel');
$articleId = '1'; //We used here '1' article id
$article = $Model->getItem($articleId);
```

Answer (score 3):

In the most generic way, you can write a query to load the articles in a list. Or, you can work with the article model.

You can check how it works in a content module or in content component:

**mod_articles_latest**

modules/mod_articles_latest/helper.php

```
    // Get an instance of the generic articles model
    $model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));

    // Set application parameters in model
    $app       = JFactory::getApplication();
    $appParams = $app->getParams();
    $model->setState('params', $appParams);

    // Set the filters based on the module params
    $model->setState('list.start', 0);
    $model->setState('list.limit', (int) $params->get('count', 5));
    $model->setState('filter.published', 1);

    // Access filter
    $access     = !JComponentHelper::getParams('com_content')->get('show_noauth');
    $authorised = JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels(JFactory::getUser()->get('id'));
    $model->setState('filter.access', $access);

    // Category filter
    $model->setState('filter.category_id', $params->get('catid', array()));

    // User filter
    $userId = JFactory::getUser()->get('id');

    switch ($params->get('user_id'))
    {
        case 'by_me' :
            $model->setState('filter.author_id', (int) $userId);
            break;
        case 'not_me' :
            $model->setState('filter.author_id', $userId);
            $model->setState('filter.author_id.include', false);
            break;

        case '0' :
            break;

        default:
            $model->setState('filter.author_id', (int) $params->get('user_id'));
            break;
    }

    // Filter by language
    $model->setState('filter.language', $app->getLanguageFilter());

    //  Featured switch
    switch ($params->get('show_featured'))
    {
        case '1' :
            $model->setState('filter.featured', 'only');
            break;
        case '0' :
            $model->setState('filter.featured', 'hide');
            break;
        default :
            $model->setState('filter.featured', 'show');
            break;
    }

    // Set ordering
    $order_map = array(
        'm_dsc' => 'a.modified DESC, a.created',
        'mc_dsc' => 'CASE WHEN (a.modified = ' . $db->quote($db->getNullDate()) . ') THEN a.created ELSE a.modified END',
        'c_dsc' => 'a.created',
        'p_dsc' => 'a.publish_up',
        'random' => 'RAND()',
    );
    $ordering = JArrayHelper::getValue($order_map, $params->get('ordering'), 'a.publish_up');
    $dir      = 'DESC';

    $model->setState('list.ordering', $ordering);
    $model->setState('list.direction', $dir);

    $items = $model->getItems();
```